# CPU used by child processes spawned by ruby

Tags: ruby, multicore

If you spawn a child process in ruby (using Kernel.system for example), can it use a different CPU to the parent process?

If so, can you use multiple threads (within the same CPU) in a parent process, and have each thread spawning a child process that can use a different CPU, even in ruby 1.8?

(Background -- it's superscript.rb from [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1374/pause-all-but-x-cpu-intensive-tasks), but rather than doing all 50 folders, I just want to do one of the folders quickly. I'm using Ubuntu Linux.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby processes are no different from any other process - they are scheduled by the OS independently, and may be distributed across CPUs according to the OS's whims.

C/Ruby 1.8 threads, on the other hand, are "green" threads, which the OS knows nothing about.  All threads in a given Ruby process will be run on the same CPU.  However, you can use threads to manage subprocesses, and those subprocesses may be scheduled across CPUs.

Comment: In regards to this question, Kernel.system creates a subprocess, not a Ruby thread.